# retrieve individual documents from an envelope that has multiple instead of getting back combined

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the rest API calling the envelope.Create() passing in a `List` of `Byte` arrays and filenames.

How can I retrieve each individual document separately after the signing ceremony?

The `GetCompletedDocument` sends me back the whole thing in one PDF. `GetEnvelopeDocumentInfo` just gets me names and URIs.

Using `/restapi/v2`

Comment: and I dont see a getdocument api in the version: DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll (v 1.4.0.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/

That should give you an idea of how to grab individual documents.